# Can we using M.C.T. show that $\int f d \mu = \sum^\infty_{n=1}\int f_n d \mu$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Want to show that if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of integrable functions and $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \int |f_n| d\mu<\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) d\mu$ is convergent to integrable function $f(x)$, and also that $\int f d \mu = \sum^\infty_{n=1}\int f_n d \mu$.

I know how to do this one using D.C.T.

Question:

(1) Can we prove this statement using M.C.T. ?

For example, for general function $f_n=f_n^+-f_n^-$, and using M.C.T. for $\sum_{j=1}^{n}f_{j=1}^+$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}f_{j=1}^-$ respectively.

(2) Can we prove this using Fubini's theorem?

Let $f(n,x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$. Since $\int_{N}\int|f(n,x)|<\infty$

Then can we apply Fubini?

Comment: Yes, applying MCT to the positive and negative parts gives the  result.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks!! Do I need to prove $\sum_{j=1}^n f_j \to \sum_j f_j$ converges? This is same as $\sum_{i}^{\infty} f_j$ converges. How to prove that?

Comment: If $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} f_j^{+} \to \sum f_j^{+}$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} f_j^{-} \to \sum f_j^{-}$  then $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} f_j \to \sum f_j$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But how to say for each x, $\sum_1^{\infty} f_j(x)$ converges a.e.?

Comment: If a function is integrable then it is finite almost everywhere. So $\sum |f_n| <\infty$ a.e.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do we need to show that $\{\sum f_j(x)=\infty\}$ is a null set?